# How to find previous days on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to achieve something like that. If today is Monday I need to go 3 days back else 1 day.

```
if datename(weekday,mydate)='monday' 
then mydate=dateadd(day,today()-3)
elseif mydate=dateadd(day,today()-1)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.

First, you need just to have `else`, not `elseif`; `elseif` is only for when you have additional conditions to consider.
Second, you have to get the parameters for your function calls correct. `dateadd` takes 3 parameters: the size of interval (a quoted string), the number of intervals to add, and the date to add the intervals to. You have only two parameters, and the first one is not quoted.
Finally, you need to make sure your initial condition is correct.  It turns out that the `datename` function returns a capitalized string ("Monday", not "monday"), which matters for the equality comparison.

All together, you end up with

```
if datename('weekday',today()) = 'Monday'
then dateadd('day',-3,today())
else dateadd('day',-1,today())
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have column called mydate

```
if datename('weekday',[mydate])='Monday' 
   THEN dateadd('day',-3,[mydate]) 
   ELSE dateadd('day',-1,[mydate]) END
```